# Oracle impdp not creating users/schema 12c -->19c

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Hey all my impdp for oracle is listing quite a few errors that look like the following:

Failing sql is:
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_AQ_IMP_INTERNAL.CLEANUP_SCHEMA_IMPORT;COMMIT; END;

ORA-39083: Object type PROCACT_SCHEMA failed to create with error:
ORA-31625: Schema OPENDEMO_SNAP is needed to import this object, but is unaccesscible
ORA-01435: user does not exist

I am importing and exporting as user system and to make double sure I ran the follow SQL commands:

GRANT DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE TO system;
GRANT DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO system;

The import and export commands are as follows:

expdp system/password directory=dp_dir transportable=always full=y dumpfile=full_tts.dmp log=full_tts_export.log

impdp system/password directory=dp_dir dumpfile=full_tts.dmp logfile=full_tts_imp.log transport_datafiles='/tmp/oracle-db/users*','/tmp/oracle-db/data*'

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

EDIT: Here is the full export log.
;;;
Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Sep 27 09:35:55 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;;
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
;;; Legacy Mode Active due to the following parameters:
;;; Legacy Mode Parameter: "log=full_tts_export.log" Location: Command Line, Replaced with: "logfile=full_tts_export.log"
;;; Legacy Mode has set reuse_dumpfiles=true parameter.
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01":  system/******** directory=dp_dir transportable=always full=y dumpfile=full_tts.dmp logfile=full_tts_export.log reuse_dumpfiles=true
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PLUGTS_FULL/FULL/PLUGTS_TABLESPACE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PLUGTS_FULL/PLUGTS_BLK

> > > ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
> > > BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_RULE_EXP_RULES".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'12.01.00.02.00'); END;
> > > ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSAUX'
> > > ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
> > > BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_RULE_EXP_RULES".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'12.01.00.02.00'); END;
> > > ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSAUX'
> > > ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
> > > BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_RULE_EXP_RULES".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'12.01.00.02.00'); END;
> > > ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSAUX'
> > > ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
> > > BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_RULE_EXP_RULES".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'12.01.00.02.00'); END;
> > > ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSAUX'
> > > ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
> > > BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_RULE_EXP_RULES".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'12.01.00.02.00'); END;
> > > ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSAUX'
> > > ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
> > > BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_RULE_EXP_RULES".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'12.01.00.02.00'); END;
> > > ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSAUX'
> > > ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
> > > BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_RULE_EXP_RULES".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'12.01.00.02.00'); END;
> > > ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSAUX'
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE_DATA
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/TABLE_DATA
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE_DATA
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
> > > Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 1002. MB
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_SYSTEM_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PROFILE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYS_USER/USER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/USER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/RADM_FPTM
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT/PROC_SYSTEM_GRANT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/ROLE_GRANT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/DEFAULT_ROLE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/ON_USER_GRANT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/RESOURCE_COST
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/DB_LINK
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TRUSTED_DB_LINK
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/DIRECTORY
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/LIBRARY/LIBRARY
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TYPE/TYPE_SPEC
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PRE_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PROCOBJ
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/POST_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/EARLY_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/TABLE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_OPTIONS/VIEWS_AS_TABLES/TABLE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/NORMAL_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOU/MARKER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/COMMENT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/IDENTITY_COLUMN
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/VIEW
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE_BODIES/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TRIGGER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/MATERIALIZED_VIEW
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/END_PLUGTS_BLK
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/FINAL_POST_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/POST_SCHEMA/PROCOBJ
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/POST_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/AUDIT_UNIFIED/AUDIT_POLICY_ENABLE
> > > Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/POST_SYSTEM_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
> > > . . exported "SYS"."KU$_USER_MAPPING_VIEW"               6.593 KB      65 rows
> > > . . exported "ORDDATA"."ORDDCM_DOCS"                     252.9 KB       9 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$CONSTRAINTS_TABLE$"                 0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."AUD$"                                    0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$LOCKROWS_INFO$"                     0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$UDTRIG_INFO$"                       0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$AUDIT_ACTIONS"               5.757 KB       8 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$DIP_EVENTS"                  5.539 KB       2 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$INSTALLATIONS"               6.960 KB       2 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$PROPS"                       6.234 KB       5 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."DAM_CLEANUP_EVENTS$"                     0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."DAM_CLEANUP_JOBS$"                       0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."DAM_CONFIG_PARAM$"                   6.531 KB      14 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_ASSOCIATION$"                       0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_CONDITION$"                         0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_FEATURE_POLICY$"                    0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_PARAMETER$"                     5.953 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_POLICY$"                        5.921 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_PROTECTION$"                        0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SENSITIVE_DATA$"                    0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SENSITIVE_TYPE$"                    0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SOURCE$"                            0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SUBPOL$"                        6.328 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."REDO_DB"                          25.59 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."REDO_LOG"                             0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$BATCH_COMPRESSIBLE_TABLES$"         0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$CONS_COLUMNS$"                      0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$ENV_VARS$"                      6.015 KB       3 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$EVENTS_INFO$"                   5.812 KB      12 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$HINT_TABLE$"                    9.453 KB      75 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$MODIFIED_TABLES$"                   0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$MP_GRAPH_WORKSPACES_TABLE$"         0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$MP_PARENT_WORKSPACES_TABLE$"        0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$NESTED_COLUMNS_TABLE$"              0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$NEXTVER_TABLE$"                 6.375 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$REMOVED_WORKSPACES_TABLE$"          0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$RESOLVE_WORKSPACES_TABLE$"          0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$RIC_LOCKING_TABLE$"                 0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$RIC_TABLE$"                         0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$RIC_TRIGGERS_TABLE$"                0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$UDTRIG_DISPATCH_PROCS$"             0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$VERSION_HIERARCHY_TABLE$"       5.984 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$VERSION_TABLE$"                     0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$VT_ERRORS_TABLE$"                   0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$WORKSPACES_TABLE$"              12.10 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$WORKSPACE_PRIV_TABLE$"          7.054 KB      10 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$WORKSPACE_SAVEPOINTS_TABLE$"        0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$AUDIT"                           0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$COMPARTMENTS"                    0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$DIP_DEBUG"                       0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$GROUPS"                          0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$LAB"                             0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$LEVELS"                          0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$POL"                             0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$POLICY_ADMIN"                    0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$POLS"                            0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$POLT"                            0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$PROFILE"                         0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$PROFILES"                        0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$PROG"                            0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$SESSINFO"                        0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$USER"                            0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$USER_COMPARTMENTS"               0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$USER_GROUPS"                     0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "LBACSYS"."OLS$USER_LEVELS"                     0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."FGA_LOG$FOR_EXPORT"                      0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."SCHEDULER_JOB_ARGS"                   0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."SCHEDULER_PROGRAM_ARGS"           9.515 KB      12 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."AUDTAB$TBS$FOR_EXPORT"               5.953 KB       2 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."DBA_SENSITIVE_DATA"                      0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."DBA_TSDP_POLICY_PROTECTION"              0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."NACL$_ACE_EXP"                       9.929 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."NACL$_HOST_EXP"                      6.914 KB       1 rows
> > > . . exported "SYS"."NACL$_WALLET_EXP"                        0 KB       0 rows
> > > . . exported "WMSYS"."WM$EXP_MAP"                        7.718 KB       3 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."TEST1"                            697.0 MB 20895367 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."TEST2"                            125.6 MB 3805424 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."TEST_SPEAKERS"                    4.876 MB  121874 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01"             3.468 MB    1842 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_02"             3.467 MB    1842 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_03"             3.469 MB    1843 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_04"             3.468 MB    1842 rows
> > > . . exported "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_05"             3.468 MB    1842 rows
> > > Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded

---

Dump file set for SYSTEM.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01 is:
/u01/app/datafiles/full_tts.dmp

---

Datafiles required for transportable tablespace DATA:
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data01.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data02.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data03.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data04.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data05.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data06.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data07.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data08.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data09.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data10.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data11.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data12.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data13.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data14.dbf
/export/u11/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data15.dbf
Datafiles required for transportable tablespace USERS:
/export/u10/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/users01.dbf
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Tue Sep 27 09:51:37 2022 elapsed 0 00:15:40

Comment: Have you created all the required users(OPENDEMO_SNAP) at target db?

Comment: Maybe this is my point of confusion. Is it required to create all users in target db before importing? It was my understanding that doing a full import/export would transfer users as well.

Comment: Can you share export log, also does export user have DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role?

Comment: I have added the full export log to the original post. I also added that role to the system user before exporting.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-90597B1B-9901-41A5-AE20-B36F6CEF6B50  Type definitions for columns of tables in the specified tablespaces are exported and imported.The schemas owning those types must be present in the target instance.This is specific to Transportable Tablespace Mode.

Comment: Also, looks like sytem user need quota on sysaux tablespace. pastebin would have been better to share log :)

Comment: I am using full mode. From above " transportable=always full=y"

I will make sure to use pastebin next time. Let me try to add that role to that user. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Keep these in mind, happy to help. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-BA07401C-6261-4B07-AD2C-06CD0A6E0BE9  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-079769D8-40F4-432F-88AD-E7264D7A2E2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the command that fixed my issue.

GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO PUBLIC;

It is my understanding that this gives permissions to all users and allowed me to skip creating a script for this.

Be warned granted unlimited tablespace can have adverse effects!